# WPF Docking last child base on what is visible

Tags: wpf, xaml

so for test purpose i have 4 objects. an accordion Nav bar and 3 Layout groups under a Layout Control. What is inside the groups at this minute is irrelevant, I want to Dock the Accordion on the left and then one of the three remaining Layout groups to fill the remaining space base on what is selected from the Accordion. I will post Code and images below.

```
        <dxlc:LayoutControl>
            <dxlc:LayoutGroup VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="myTag1" Header="LayoutGroup" View="Tabs">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="General" >
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox Content="Enable Image Processing"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Content="Enable GIS"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Content="Enable Walksort"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Content="Enable eMail Dialog Box"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Content="Enable Work Queue"></CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Content="Enable Absent Vote Queue"></CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        </dxlc:LayoutGroup>

            <dxlc:LayoutGroup x:Name="myTag2" Header="LayoutGroup" View="Tabs">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="ToolBars">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="Show Version"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Show Group"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Show User"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Show Time"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Show Date"></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>

            <dxlc:LayoutGroup x:Name="myTag3" Header="LayoutGroup" View="Tabs" IsEnabled="False">
                <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="Rolling Register">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox Content="Display Grid on Register"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Colour Register"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Hide Future Changes on Published Register"></CheckBox>
                        <CheckBox Content="Warn on Forename and Surname Change"></CheckBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
</dockpanel>
```

Above is the three layout groups, below will be the Accordion, both are wrapped in

```
    <dockpanel>
    <dxnav:OfficeNavigationBar DockPanel.Dock="Left" CustomizationButtonVisibility="Hidden">
        <dxa:AccordionControl>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left">
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonUp="ChkShow_Checked1" MouseRightButtonUp="ChkShow_Unchecked1"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Toolbars" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonUp="ChkShow_Checked2" MouseRightButtonUp="ChkShow_Unchecked2"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Rolling Register" Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonUp="ChkShow_Checked3" MouseRightButtonUp="ChkShow_Unchecked3"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Register Screen" Cursor="Hand"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Elector List Colours" Cursor="Hand"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="SMTP Settings" Cursor="Hand"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Register" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Register"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Terminology"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Orders"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Areas"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Email Drag'N'Drop"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Duplicate-check options"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="WP/Reports" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Wordprocessor"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Report"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Paths"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Report Scheduler"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Image Processing" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Canvass Image Queue"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Absent Votes Image Queue"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Canvass" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Exclude the Following"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Standard Layout and Output"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="System" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Version"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Paths"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Find"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Key"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Settings"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Authority" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Authority Details"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Registration Officer"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Dates/Costs" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Dates"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Register Costs"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Walksort" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Walksort Rates"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Keys" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General Keys"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Audit Register Only"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Published Register Only"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Acknowledgements" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Automatic Acknowledgements"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Auto Text" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Auto Text Entries"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Processing" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Published to Audit"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Audit to Published"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Rolling Register Amendment"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Rolling Register Month End"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Rolling Register Move Elector"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="NLPG Integration Settings"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Management" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Poll Card"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Election Build"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Ballot Paper"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Absent Vote"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Markers" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Markers"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="IER" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Communication Details"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="IER RAG Status Colours"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Web Applications"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>
            <dxa:AccordionItem Header="DocumentQ" ExpandButtonPosition="Right" GlyphPosition="Left" >
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="General"/>
                <dxa:AccordionItem Header="Documents"/>
            </dxa:AccordionItem>                
        </dxa:AccordionControl>
    </dxnav:OfficeNavigationBar>
```

I have tried separating the three Layout groups into separate Layout Controllers although that does not fill the screen as I Believe there is no "last child" to fill.

[The General Tab should take the remaining screen space but because docker is seeing the last child as Layoutcontrol it is sharing the screen space with the other two tabs where the visibility has been set to False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXgPX.png)

Comment: What control library are you using? `dxlc` isn't a "standard" namespace for WPF controls.

Comment: developer express

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is I should have been doing this through Navigation pages.